# ngDialog not updating $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I'm opening a "popup" using

`$scope.dialog = ngDialog.open({
    template: 'addSurveyQuestion',
    controller: 'EventSurveysCtrl',
    scope: $scope
});`

Within the template I call a function, which creates an AJAX request but upon me pushing that data to $scope using `$scope.eventSurveyQuestions.push({data here});` it doesn't appear in the main $scope. Its as if there are 2 $scope variables, one for main page and one for ngDialog.

How can I add data to the main $scope from within a process that was initiated from within an ngDialog popup?

Comment: Updating $scope.$parent was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `ngDialog` but I took a look into its [documentation about the scope property](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scope-object).

> Scope object that will be passed to the dialog. **If you use a
>   controller with separate $scope service this object will be passed to
>   the $scope.$parent param**.

You don't show very much of how you built your actual controller so I can just guess that you may want to access `$scope.$parent` instead of plain `$scope`.

You may also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716493/ngdialog-scope-variables-not-being-updated-by-ngmodel-fields-in-dialog-when-us?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

you can add data to the main scope by scope.$parent or $scope.$parent

Possibly you can use $rootScope to set and get variables values from there

Answer (score 0):

No need to use scope in dialog.open, if you opening your dialog from 'main scope'.

Try

```
$scope.dialog = ngDialog.open({
    template: 'addSurveyQuestion',
    controller: 'EventSurveysCtrl',
});
```

and, in your dialog controller -

```
app.controller('EventSurveysCtrl', ["$scope",.... fucntion($scope,...) {
    //now the '$scope' is your main scope
}
```