# Angularjs: ngDialog only binds and modifies with objects; not basic variables.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I've already found a "solution" to this problem; I was just hoping someone might be able to provide a reason why it works.

This jsFiddle demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/s1ca0h9x/137/

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="myApplication">
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
<a href="" ng-click="ShowNgDialog()">Click Here</a>

        <input type="text" ng-model="accountNum" />
        <span>{{accountNum}}</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

ANGULARJS

```
var myApplication = angular.module('myApplication', ['ngDialog']);

myApplication.controller('MainController', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.accountNum = 'test';
    $scope.ShowNgDialog = function () {
        ngDialog.open({            
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="accountNum"/></div>',
            plain: true,
            scope:$scope

        });
    }    
});
```

When I try and manipulate a scope **variable** (in this case: $scope.accountNum = 'test') from the dialog, it doesn't bind/save it back to the model.

...However, when I change that variable into an object, things just magically work, as shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s1ca0h9x/138/

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="myApplication">
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
<a href="" ng-click="ShowNgDialog()">Click Here</a>

        <input type="text" ng-model="FormData.accountNum" />
        <span>{{FormData.accountNum}}</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

ANGULARJS

```
var myApplication = angular.module('myApplication', ['ngDialog']);

myApplication.controller('MainController', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.FormData={accountNum: ''};
    $scope.ShowNgDialog = function () {
        ngDialog.open({            
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="FormData.accountNum"/></div>',
            plain: true,
            scope:$scope

        });
    }    
});
```

I also tested both options using a template linking to a file, and not using plain:true, in addition to trying ngDialog.openConfirm, etc. I essentially rebuilt the solution found here [ngDialog $scope variables not being updated by ngModel fields in $dialog when using scope: $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716493/ngdialog-scope-variables-not-being-updated-by-ngmodel-fields-in-dialog-when-us) piece by piece, and finally the only change that seemed to work was using an object instead of a basic scope variable.
Am I approaching this wrong, or missing some fundamental aspects of data binding?

Comment: i think this could respond your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128502/8303694

Comment: it has something to be with two-way-binding.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has nothing to do with the binding. I will explain what I did understood when I dig into the code of [**ngDialog**](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/js/ngDialog.js) and [**AngularJS**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js?source=c).

I think the first case is not working as you expect, because `$scope.accountNum = 'test';` is a simple string which is a primitive type and **is not mutable**([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable)) or in other words is **immutable**:

> Mutable is a type of variable that can be changed. In JavaScript, only
>   objects and arrays are mutable, **not primitive values**.
>   (*You can make a variable name point to a new value, but the previous
>   value is still held in memory. Hence the need for garbage collection.*)
>
> A **mutable** object is an object whose state **can be modified after it is
>   created**.
>
> **Immutables** are the objects whose state **cannot be changed once the
>   object is created.**
>
> **String and Numbers are Immutable.**

So, in short words, this was the reason why the first variant is not working as you want :)

---

Now let's have a look on [**this**](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/js/ngDialog.js#L528) code of ngDialog, which is a part of [**open()**](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/js/ngDialog.js#L500) method:

```
var scope;
scopes[dialogID] = scope = angular.isObject(options.scope) ? options.scope.$new() : $rootScope.$new();
```

in your case we are calling `options.scope.$new()`, because you specified `scope` in options when opening the dialog.

Now let's go and check [**this**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js?source=c#L242) angular code:

```
$new: function (isolate, parent) {
    var child;  
    parent = parent || this;

    if (isolate) {
        child = new Scope();
        child.$root = this.$root;
    } else {
        if (!this.$$ChildScope) {
            this.$$ChildScope = createChildScopeClass(this); // <---- WE ARE COMING HERE NOW
        }
        child = new this.$$ChildScope();
    }
    ...
```

function [**createChildScopeClass**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js?source=c#L85) looks like:

```
function createChildScopeClass(parent) {
    function ChildScope() {
        this.$$watchers = this.$$nextSibling =
                this.$$childHead = this.$$childTail = null;
        this.$$listeners = {};
        this.$$listenerCount = {};
        this.$$watchersCount = 0;
        this.$id = nextUid();
        this.$$ChildScope = null;
    }
    ChildScope.prototype = parent; /* <--- They simply assign the derived scope 
     as prototype of the new one (which is going to be the scope of the ngDialog) */
    return ChildScope;
}
```

We can see that `function createChildScopeClass()` simply assigns the parent scope's prototype to the new one (*which is going to be the scope of the opened ngDialog*)

And a sample that is demonstrating mutability and immutability:

```js
var test = 'test'; 
var test2 = test;
test2 = 'new value';
console.log('test = ' + test + ' // test2 = ' + test2);

var testObj = {test: 'test'};
var test2Obj = testObj;
test2Obj.test = 'new value';
console.log('testObj.test = ' + testObj.test + ' // test2Obj.test = ' + test2Obj.test);
```

### Conclusion

Use **objects** or **arrays** in your parent scope if you want binding to work in the derived scope. Sample using AngularJS:

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.primitive = 'test';
  $scope.obj = {
    test: 'test initial'
  };

  $scope.newScope = $scope.$new();
  $scope.newScope.primitive = 'test 2';
  $scope.newScope.obj.test = 'updated value';

}]);

app.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <table>
      <thead><tr><th>Property</th><th>Value</th><th></th></tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>primitive</td>
          <td>{{ primitive }}</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="primitive"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>obj.test</td>
          <td>{{ obj.test }}</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.test"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>newScope.primitive</td>
          <td>{{ newScope.primitive }}</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="newScope.primitive"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>newScope.obj.test</td>
          <td>{{ newScope.obj.test }}</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="newScope.obj.test"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked, is to create a function in the base controller, and call the function from ngDialog controller.

Ex:

```
myApplication.controller('MainController', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.accountNum = 'test';
    $scope.ShowNgDialog = function () {
        ngDialog.open({            
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="accountNum"/></div>',
            plain: true,
            scope:$scope,
            controller: ['$scope',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.updateVar();
                }]
        });
    };

    $scope.updateVar = function(){
        $scope.accountNum = "changed";
    }
});
```